# Is there a way to scan the 5 digit add-on barcode using Apple's built-in iOS barcode API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, barcode, barcode-scanner, avcapturesession

Is there a way, using Apple's built-in iOS barcode API, to scan the last 5 digits of an add-on barcode?

If not, is there a free SDK solution out that that is known to work well and has stayed up to date with the latest iOS versions? ZBar works but is WAY outdated.

See the comic book example here:

[image]

Comment: have you got success to scan your barcodes

Comment: Still using ZBar. :(

Answer (score 0):

Tried about 10 different online barcode detectors, and neither of them can decode that barcode.

[image]

Seems this barcode has some special format which is not supported with current barcode readers...

Comment: Scandit works on the code but it's a high-cost SDK. Just tried it myself and it works fine.

It's a UPC-A 5-digit add-on and must be scanned with the initial 12-digit code. It's generally not used as a standalone barcode. It's very common on comic books and magazines to get pricing information, cover variations, printings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your having trouble with Apples Barcode API i suggest trying MLKit from Firebase i am able to scan and get OCR from image with few lines of code.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/read-barcodes

Comment: It looks like this is a good free choice for additional barcode types, but UPC-A +5 and +2 don't appear to be listed. I've sent them an e-mail asking to add those barcode types to ML Kit.

Answer (score 0):

I tried https://github.com/hyperoslo/BarcodeScanner. It is okay with the swift 4.1. Also, It is reading the larger barcode under the direct sales label on left but not the smaller on the right with 00113 label above it. Can you please confirm that these barcodes are valid? As the application from this wrapper is working on other barcodes.

Comment: Yes, the barcodes are valid. Search Google Images for "comic book barcode" to get many examples. As I said in the post, old versions of ZBar work, but because the Objective-C code hasn't been updates in years, it's starting to become incompatible and crashing.